# ElasticSearch snapshots not visible in S3 repository

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I have an ElasticSearch cluster with the snapshot repository configured via repository-s3 plugin.
Repository has verification status "connected".
I see the list of snapshots made by ElasticSearch, they have status "completed" and are assigned to the mentioned repository.

When I'm looking into S3 directory assigned to the repository, it is empty. I'm using the same credentials as ElasticSearch.

Why is the bucket directory empty?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the same region?

Comment: The bucket exists only in one region

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution- the path in bucket configured for my repository had a prefix "/". Removing the prefix caused the snapshots appear in the S3.
That's weird that Elasticsearch reported everything as correct.